# Is there a reference to Voldemort in 12 Angry Men?

Tags: reference, harry-potter, 12-angry-men

At time 47:48 of *12 Angry Men (1957)* the guy in the hat says what I believe to be "Voldemort please, eh?". Was this a reference to the character in Harry Potter? How could it be since the first book was released in 1997?

Comment: *"How could it be since the first book was released in 1997?"* - Uh, answer found, no? By the way, I guess you're talking about the original and not the remake?

Comment: Maybe Harry Potter is a true story?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, the lines you are mishearing are actually:

> **Juror #5**: Look, lawyers aren't infallible, you know.
>
> **Juror #7**: Baltimore, please. Huh?

This is referring to near the start where he is asked:

> **Juror #7**: You a [Yankee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_Yankees) fan?
>
> **Juror #5**: No, [Baltimore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baltimore_Orioles).
>
> **Juror #7**: Baltimore? That's like being hit in the head with a crowbar once a day.